# Redefinition of value compile error

Tags: r, rcpp

After re-installing Xcode and Command Line Tools on my MacBook Pro (OS High Sierra 10.13.2, I am experiencing difficulties with compilation via sourceCpp() in R.

Specifically, I get the error

```
>sourceCpp("cube-sample.cpp")
clang++  -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG -    I../inst/include   -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/Rcpp/include" -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/RcppArmadillo/include" -I"/Users/jarrettphillips/Desktop/HAC simulation" -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c cube-sample.cpp -o cube-sample.o
Error in sourceCpp("cube-sample.cpp") : 
Error 1 occurred building shared library.
```

Any ideas with what may be going on here? Perhaps it is a PATH issue?]

This is included at the top of my .cpp file:

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
#define ARMA_DONT_PRINT_OPENMP_WARNING
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
#include <RcppArmadilloExtensions/sample.h>
#include <set>
using namespace Rcpp;
```

And here is my full C++ code

```
int sample_one(int n) {
return n * unif_rand();
} 

int sample_n_distinct(const IntegerVector& x, 
                      int k,
                      const int * pop_ptr) {

  IntegerVector ind_index = RcppArmadillo::sample(x, k, false); 
  std::set<int> distinct_container;

  for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
    distinct_container.insert(pop_ptr[ind_index[i]]);
  }

  return distinct_container.size();
 }

// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::Cube<int> fillCube(const arma::Cube<int>& pop,
                         const IntegerVector& specs,
                         int perms,
                         int K) {

  int num_specs = specs.size();
  arma::Cube<int> res(perms, num_specs, K);

  IntegerVector specs_C = specs - 1;
  const int * pop_ptr;
  int i, j, k;

  for (i = 0; i < K; i++) {
    for (k = 0; k < num_specs; k++) {
      for (j = 0; j < perms; j++) {
        pop_ptr = &(pop(0, sample_one(perms), sample_one(K)));
        res(j, k, i) = sample_n_distinct(specs_C, k + 1, pop_ptr);
      }
    }
  }

  return res;
}
```

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

EDIT: The above code improvement but now I get the error:

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-    L/usr/local/gfortran/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin15/6.1.0'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/gfortran/lib'
Error in fillCube(pop, num.specs, perms, K) : 
Not compatible with requested type: [type=character; target=integer].
```

Could it have to do with data types in my native R code? What I would like actually is the 'pop' variable to contain character values (instead of int).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure Xcode CLI was installed properly?

Applications -> Utilities -> Terminal

```
xcode-select --install
```

Then grab the installer for *R* CRAN clang4 binary (*disclaimer: I built the installer*):

https://github.com/coatless/r-macos-clang

---

**Edit**

With the code being posted, this isn't a compiler error. This error originates from re-defining the input vector to contain the *size* of the input.

c.f.

```
toad3.cpp:32:7: error: redefinition of 'specs' with a different type: 'int' vs 'const IntegerVector &' (aka 'const Vector<13> &')   int specs = specs.size();
      ^ toad3.cpp:28:47: note: previous definition is here
                         const IntegerVector& specs,

toad3.cpp:33:19: error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'arma::Cube<int>'
arma::Cube<int> res(perms, specs, K);
                  ^   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

toad3.cpp:40:17: error: value of type 'Rcpp::sugar::Comparator_With_One_Value<13, Rcpp::sugar::greater<13>, true, Vector<13, PreserveStorage> >' is not contextually convertible to 'bool'
    for (k = 0; k < specs; k++) {
                ^~~~~~~~~
3 errors generated.
```

Enacting the following three changes in `fillCube` fixes the errors:

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::Cube<int> fillCube(const arma::Cube<int>& pop,
                         const IntegerVector& specs,
                         int perms,
                         int K) {

  int num_specs = specs.size();             // change variable
  arma::Cube<int> res(perms, num_specs, K); // change variable

  IntegerVector specs_C = specs - 1;
  const int * pop_ptr;
  int i, j, k;

  for (i = 0; i < K; i++) {
    for (k = 0; k < num_specs; k++) { // change variable
      for (j = 0; j < perms; j++) {
        pop_ptr = &(pop(0, sample_one(perms), sample_one(K)));
        res(j, k, i) = sample_n_distinct(specs_C, k + 1, pop_ptr);
      }
    }
  }

  return res;
}
```

Comment: Yes CLT is already installed according to xcode-select --install. How do I install clang4?

Comment: No worries, I found the installer, which is currently being downloaded.

Comment: But now I still get the exact same error... I am uncertain what is going on. Any ideas?

Comment: Yes I can post output for clarification.

Comment: I have posted further details. Hopefully we can figure it out.

Comment: I have posted the relevant C++ code. The full R code is too much to post and run I believe.

Comment: I started to look at this too a couple hours ago when the code was in even worse shape (templated `<char>` and whatnot).  There were loads of mostly sloppy beginner errors that are orthogonal to the fight with macOS which here seems mostly a distraction.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel I am definitely a beginner with Rcpp, but my primary language is indeed R. Your package should work wonders for me in speeding up my algorithm! Thanks!

Comment: @JarrettPhillips if everything works. Please upvote and accept the answer!

Comment: @coatless Thanks you! I am trying it now! I will upvote and accept soon

Comment: @coatless Definitely an improvement, but now I get another error. Please see the post edit.

Comment: @JarrettPhillips The general recommendation is that you try to walk before you line up for the regional championship in a sprint.  Get simple examples working first.  Then make them more complex.  One. Step. At. A. Time.

Comment: @JarrettPhillips You tried to edit coatless 's answer.  Wrong.  Edit your question instead.